# Rails view template path loading seems incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem where Rails is searching an additional subdirectory based on the controller path. Is there a way to get rails to stop searching one extra subdirectory? I kind of like the directory structure that I have now. Here's the details:

Rails will return this error message. As you can see, it's going for `v1` twice:

```
Template is missing
Missing template api/v1/v1/print
```

I have a controller in `app/controllers/api/v1/v1_controller.rb` and a view in `app/views/api/v1/print.html.erb`

The specific route in config/routes.rb is (semi-truncated):

```
namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1 do
        match "v1/print",
            :to => "v1#print"
    end
end
```

Based on the routes, it looks OK. Rake routes show this:

```
api_v1_print GET|POST /api/v1/print(.:format)  api/v1/v1#print {:format=>"html"}
```

Why is it going one directory too deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Rails assumes there's a subdirectory per each controller. The duplication is formed since you have v1 in the module and in the controller name. I wouldn't go against Rails' conventions. Instead I would change the name of the controller to API controller (or something similar) and put the templates under the directory called API.

In case you still want to do this, simply use `render` within your print action and specify the exact file you'd like to use (see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html))

Answer (score 1):

<s>just remove the `v1` from the match, like this:</s>

```
namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1 do
        match "print",
            :to => "v1#print"
    end
end
```

**EDIT**

sorry, the problem is in your template folder.

```
app/views/api/v1/print.html.erb
app/views/(namespace)/(module)/(action) <- you have forgoten the controller
```

the right one would be:

```
app/views/api/v1/v1/print.html.erb
```

Comment: It will then expect a controller at ```api/v1_controller.rb```. This isn't what I want though.

Comment: I have looked at your new comment and I have tried this. It works, however it's not what I want. I want my view to be at app/views/api/v1/print.html.erb. Notice how it is not two-directories deep.

Comment: have you tried to remove the ``v1`` from the match line after the new edit?

Comment: i think i understand your problem. you don't want the ``v1/v1`` on the path to the template. but since you are using the same name for the ``scope`` and the ``controller`` this is not possible to change. what i recomend is that you create the controller with a diferent name, like ``default`` or ``handler`` and turn the ``scope module: :v1`` to a namespace, so all its controllers will be concealed in one single folder